# How to show a dialog on click of a combobox item using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox

I am having a combo box control in which I had inserted three items(For instance X,Y,Z respectively). I want to show a dialog when "X" item in the combobox is clicked. In order show a dialog upon click on "X" item, I was able to handle it in "SelectionChanged" event. But the problem here is when I click on the same item no event is getting triggered and as a result I am not able to show a dialog on click on "X" item.

How can I accomplish this issue using MVVM pattern.

I am very new to WPF, please be kind with your answers.

Comment: I created a **GitHub** project to solve this problem. You can find it [here](https://github.com/mike-eason/MVVM_WindowCommands).

Comment: Good question. But why do you need such a behavior? When user clicks on an item, a dialog is displayed. Then why should user click on the same item again? And showing a dialog box again is really required??

You could do it with binding maybe. Bind the selected item and change it to some default value on Selection changed. There is no click event available, so you can't track the click. 

I think it's possible to do with interactivity.